# How are the 4 tables for revisionable and translatable entities in Drupal 8 meant to be used?

Tags: entities, 8

There are 4 tables for each type of entity,

1. entity
2. entity_revision
3. entity_field_data
4. entity_field_revision

How exactly are the individual tables meant to be used?

Answer (score 5):

The issue queue always covers the decision making process and git blame usually shows the node ids. In this case:

https://drupal.org/node/1498674 https://drupal.org/node/2057401

This is suboptimal and the multilingual team is working on removing SQL queries touching entity table so that the entity storage class can make decisions on the schemas. This is happening at https://drupal.org/node/2068325